# ODE with Holder drift - Cauchy-Peano theorem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Consider the following ODE:
$$
x′(t)=b(x(t)),\quad x(0)=x_0.
$$
If $b$ is bounded and Holder continuous, then the Cauchy-Peano theorem ensures that there exists a solution to the above equation (but in general not unique). The question is:

is it possible that there always exists a solution $x_t(x_0)$
 which depends Lipschitz continuous in $x_0$? Or $x_0\to x_t(x_0)$
 is one-to-one?

Many thanks for the answers!

Comment: Hey Wenguang, welcome to MO. (a) Did you mean a *family* of solutions $x_t (x_0)$ such that they are Lipschitzin $x_0$ for all $t\geq 0$? (b) How can $x_0 \to x_t (x_0)$ be one-to-one if there's no uniqueness?

Comment: If we let $K_t(x_0)$ stand for the set of the values at $t > 0$ of all possible solutions taking the value $x_0$ at time zero then, under the assumption that $b$ is continuous, the mapping $$x_0 \mapsto K_t(x_0)$$ is, for  $t$ fixed, upper hemi-continuous (in the modern terminology).  Jean Duchon's example below shows that its need not be continuous in the Hausdorff topology.  For more, see G. R. Sell's paper _On the fundamental theory of ordinary
differential equations_, Journal of Differential Equations **1** (1965), 370-392.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose e.g. $b(x) = \sqrt{x}$ for $0 \le x \le 4$.  If $0 < x_0 < 4$, the solution with $x(0) = x_0$ is $$x_t(x_0) = \left(\frac{t+2\sqrt{x_0}}{2}\right)^2$$
which is unique in $-\sqrt{x_0} \le t \le 4 - 2\sqrt{x_0}$.  But at a given $t > 0$, this is
$t^2/4 + t \sqrt{x_0} + x_0^2$, which is not a Lipschitz function of $x_0 \in (0,4)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $b(x)=|x|^{-1/2}x$ (truncated for large $|x|$ for boundedness). Then, for small $t>0$, one has $x_t(x_0)>ct^2$ for $x_0>0$, but $x_t(x_0)<-ct^2$ for $x_0<0$, so that $x_t$ is discontinuous, whatever $x_t(0)$ (which can be anywhere in $[-ct^2,+ct^2]$).